# How do I convert a sequence to an array?

Tags: arrays, sequence, nim-lang

```
import strutils
source = readFile("example.txt")
var lines = source.split('\n')
```

I'm reading a file into a string, then splitting it into lines.

Is there any way I could convert the sequence to an array so it doesn't take up so much space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of an `array` must be known at compile time so it cannot be used here. I believe more details about your requirements are needed to undestand why seq[T] "take up so much space" for you.

Looking at seq[T] type declaration [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/b55fd9e4ec0fe3d309e5acb50b785020db18291e/lib/core/seqs.nim#L15) it doesn't look like a lot of overhead to me unless 1000s of small sequences are being allocated.

FYI `UncheckedArray` exist (see [Unchecked arrays](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-unchecked-arrays)) but they are not memory safe and require you to do extra work to use them.